# Signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available error while installing docker

Tags: docker

I am unable to install docker with:

```
sudo sh -c "echo deb https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"
```

error log:

> GPG error: https://get.docker.com docker Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D8576A8BA88D21E9

Comment: Personally was getting same issue, but uninstall/re-install Docker to most recent version fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution, I was trying to install docker 1.5 on a 32-bit Ubuntu, whereas the documentation says it needs 64 bit Ubuntu.

check [here](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/) in **Prerequisites** section

Answer (score 15):

Seems like the **getting started page** has changed.

**Aug 2017**

`curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/debian/#install-using-the-repository

**Aug 2019**

The link to the installation page has changed again

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian

Answer (score 5):

If don't want to use those commands from manual http://docs.docker.com/linux/step_one/:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install wget
$ wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

there is what you need:

```
 $ wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

PS:
https://docs.docker.com/installation/debian/

Answer (score 4):

The apt has a set of trusted keys and sometimes we only need to add the one that is missing.

You could have added the key just by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D8576A8BA88D21E9
```

Greetings.